# Odd Number of master nodes

Tags: elasticsearch

I was informed to use odd number of nodes to avoid split brain problem and also voting of master node is easy if the odd number of master nodes is configured.

However, say the cluster is configured with 5 nodes and one master node is down - then , there will be effectively 4 nodes ( again even number) - wont it be the same challenge with voting of master nodes ?

PS : it is not limited to Elastic Search alone, but to all distributed systems in general where master election happens through election process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that you need [more than half of](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/modules-discovery-quorums.html) the eligible master nodes in order to keep the cluster operational.

**Scenario (3 master nodes, minimum number for quorum is 2)**

Node A goes out, B and C can decide on a new master and A cannot become the master

**Scenario (4 master nodes, minimum number for quorum is 3)**

Node A goes out, B, C and D can decide on a new master and A cannot become the master. You can see here that going from 3 to 4 nodes, you didn't increase your resiliency. You can't lose two nodes.

**Scenario (5 master nodes, minimum number for quorum is 3)**
Node A and B go out, C, D and E can decide on a new master and A and B cannot. You can see here that going from 3 to 5 nodes, you did increase your resiliency.

It's not only the number of nodes in your cluster. It's that number with the quorum strategy that makes an odd number of master nodes the better choice. Moreover, the split brain problem is taken care of by the minimum master nodes needed in order to have a quorum. You will not have a split brain as long as more than half of your master nodes (which can vote) are needed in order to elect a new master node.

Comment: What I understood is, Even with 2 master-eligible nodes there is no risk of split-brain. The worst thing with a cluster with just 2 master-eligible nodes is you lose half-or-more of them (i.e. one) and the cluster stops working until they come back.

Answer (score 1):

**Simple answer**:- "An odd-size cluster tolerates the same number of failures as an even-size cluster but with fewer nodes"

As you are aware, the rule of thumb is that `discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes` should be set to N/2 + 1, where N is the number of master eligible nodes in the cluster. For example, in the case of a 3-node cluster, the minimum_master_nodes should be set to 3/2 + 1 = 2 (rounding down to the nearest integer).

Simple explanation will be ([Ref:](https://etcd.io/docs/v3.5/faq/#what-is-failure-tolerance)); If am having a 3 or 4 node cluster, the cluster can tolerate the loss of only a single master-eligible node. And if I am having a 5 or 6 node cluster, it can tolerate the loss of 2 master-eligible node.

Then why should I go with even number of nodes?

It will cause **1)** The cost for 1 more machine, without increasing the fault tolerance. **2)** With the creation of more nodes, failures of individual node became more likely. **3)** Mostly we partition the nodes in 2 different availability zones. A cluster that has an even distribution will soon become non-operational if some network failure occurs in one AZ. Split brains won't happen, but availability is compromised.

Hope this answer helps!